# play framework debug from custom running port

Tags: debugging, playframework

I want to be able to do the following

```
play debug "run 9054"
```

But from within the play console yields this.

```
play
[app01] debug "run 9054"
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: debug (similar: idea)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: debug (similar: debianSign)
[error] debug "run 9054"
[error]      ^
```

The reason I want to do this is to be able to run the h2-browser and debug from a custom run port at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start the play console in debug mode first:

```
play debug
```

And then from within the play console you can give your run command with custom port number:

```
run 9054
```